# Oracle check constraint with case when

Tags: oracle

What is the right way of writing something like this in ORACLE and is it possible:

```
ALTER TABLE REQUESTER ADD CONSTRAINT chk_account_status CHECK   
(CASE WHEN (account_status='R' or account_status='A') THEN   
(email is not null and address is not null and password is not null and mobile_phone is not null) END);
```

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Thank you,
mismas

[EDIT]

This is how I have done it now:

```
ALTER TABLE REQUESTER ADD CONSTRAINT CK_account_status 
CHECK ((account_status='R' or account_status='A') AND
(email is not null AND MOBILE_PHONE is not null 
AND PASSWORD is not null AND ADDRESS is not null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE`, but a bit of boolean logic:

```
    ( 
        (account_status='R' or account_status='A')
          AND 
        (email is not null and address is not null and password is not null and mobile_phone is not null)
    )     
OR
     not (account_status='R' or account_status='A')
```

You can rewrite this in a more compact way, I used this one because it's quite self-explanatory, given your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I try to write it that way I get an error ORA-02293: cannot validate (CK_ACCOUNT_STATUS) - check constraint violated, although all rows in my table have account_status='N' (not the one being checked) I will edit my question and post the constraint I wrote

Comment: The code you posted is only a part of the code I posted, that's why it does not work for records with `account_status='N'`. You missed the `OR...` part